# Can't get program to recognize controller.h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I created a new project in IOS using XCode and cannot get my code to recognize the controller WebViewController using the self command. Below is my code:

```
   #import "MainViewController.h"
   #import "WebViewController.h"

    @interface MainViewController ()
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview;
    @end

   @implementation MainViewController

   - (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle: 
   (NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
                     bundle: (NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
   {
     self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibNameOrNil];    
     return self;
    }

   - (IBAction)getWebpage: (id) sender
    {
    self.WebViewController.URL = // error message here
      @"http://www.mywebsite.com";

     }
```

Below is the contents of the WebViewController.h file.

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
  @interface WebViewController: UIViewController
  @property (nonatomic) NSURL *URL;
  @end
```

The error message is "Property WebViewController not found on object of type MainViewController."  I have used this command many times on other projects so why is it not working on this project?    What am I missing?  Both files are listed in my project navigator list.

Comment: The error is clear. You are attempting to access a property named `WebViewController` in your `MainViewController` class. There is no such property. What you probably want to do is have a property (or local variable) with a type of `WebViewController ` in your `MainViewController` class. Then you can access the `URL` property of that property (or local variable).

Comment: Thank you for your answer  I have been away from XCode for awhile and am trying to get back into it after working with Android.

Comment: FYI - Don't confuse a programming language (Objective-C), an editor (Xcode), and an OS (Android). Those are three independent concepts. Your issue is specific to a given programming language.